# extract and remove tag using simple html dom parser

Tags: php

extract and remove tag using simple html dom parser (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

I want to get rid of this

```
<span class="pull left"></span>
```

php

```
foreach($html->find('span[class="pull-left"]') as $date){
    //
}
```

what's next? Can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Post a sample that represents what you are trying to parse and the desired result.

Comment: @alkis just remove a tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($html->find('span[class=pull-left]') as $date){
    $date->parentNode->removeChild($date);
}
```

or

```
foreach($html->find('span[class=pull-left]') as $date){
    echo $date->outertext = '';
 }
```

Comment: Call to a member function removeChild()

Comment: @user3522725 If it worked mark Accept so others with similar problem can get help.. :)

Comment: Try the second code. I just edited. Both of them should work.

Comment: post your $html intilization?

Comment: Also, I have update the codes please see if it works