# PHP remove all HTML except img tags

Tags: php, regex

I want to remove html tag except img tag

Strip tags are not suitable, but missing data

Please refer to the code below.

Do you have any other options? ex) regex ..

code :

```
<?php 

$html = '<img src=""> <p>ddd</p> adsfasdfasd assdf<img>dd</imgasdfasdf <<<<<<< <i> dfadsfas </i>';

echo strip_tags($html, "<img>");

?>
```

result :

```
<img src=""> ddd adsfasdfasd assdf<img>dd
```

i wan't

```
<img src=""> ddd adsfasdfasd assdf<img>dd</imgasdfasdf <<<<<<< dfadsfas
```

Comment: `<img>` is not a valid closing HTML tag.  Your HTML has some problems.

Comment: Dom parser would be much bettee option rather than regex https://stackoverflow.com/q/24098976/6160662

Comment: If there are not many different tags, you could just replace them with empty string with ```$find = array('<p>','</p>','<i>','</i>');
    $html = str_replace($find,'',$html);```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this library or package for your solution:

[PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/)